# How can I join two tables( both derived from self join) to create a third table?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to solve the question https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Self_join, self joins Question number #10 specifically which says that :

> Find the routes involving two buses that can go from Craiglockhart to Lochend. Show the bus no. and company for the first bus, the name of the stop for the transfer, and the bus no. and company for the second bus.'.

I have my code and somehow it's giving me the error saying :

> DUPLICATE column name 'num'

Here is my code :

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM route a JOIN route b 
    ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
    JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
    JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
    WHERE stopa.name = 'Craiglockhart') big  
                              /* [big] table Gives all buses from 
    craiglockhart */

    JOIN


    (SELECT *
    FROM route a JOIN route b 
    ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
    JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
    JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
    WHERE stopa.name = 'Lochend') small
                              /*[small] Gives all buses from Lochend */
    ON big.b.stop = small.b.stop
                             /*Trying to join the two tables on the basis of 
    the matching values from [big].b.stop field with [small].b.stop */
```

I am not sure if this will give the desired result. If it does is it an efficient way? if not can someone help me write and explain to me how it will work thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you made this:  `ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num`

-> it returns the same value for the column `num` - so it's a duplicate.

Use indexes - for exmaple: `a.num` & `b.num`:

```
SELECT a.num
FROM route a JOIN route b 
ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num

--OR

SELECT b.num
FROM route a JOIN route b 
ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
```

`ON big.b.stop = small.b.stop` also drops an error

correct answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.num, x.company,x.name,y.num,y.company
FROM (

select a.num as num, a.company as company, stopb.name as name
FROM route a
JOIN route b
ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
WHERE stopa.name = 'Craiglockhart') x

JOIN

(select a.num as num, a.company as company, stopb.name as name
FROM route a
JOIN route b
ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
WHERE stopa.name = 'Lochend') y

ON x.name = y.name 

ORDER BY x.num
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is marked as « Correct answer » by sqlzoo.

It works by first selecting all lines that stop at Craiglockhart, and, on the other hand, all those that stop at Lochend. Each of this searches requires two JOINs (stops + route).

Finally, the query locates all stops that belong to both lines, using a special JOIN with EXISTS conditions.

```
SELECT
    r1.num,
    r1.company,
    s3.name,
    r2.num,
    r2.company
FROM 
    stops s1
    INNER JOIN route r1 ON r1.stop = s1.id
    INNER JOIN stops s2 ON s2.name = 'Lochend'
    INNER JOIN route r2 ON r2.stop = s2.id
    INNER JOIN stops s3
        ON EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM route
            WHERE 
                num = r1.num 
                AND company = r1.company
                AND stop = s3.id
        )
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM route
            WHERE 
                num = r2.num 
                AND company = r2.company
                AND stop = s3.id
        )
WHERE 
    s1.name = 'Craiglockhart'
```

Answer (score 0):

About `DUPLICATE COLUMN num`:

In case of self-join you have **double set of columns** (including column `num`): one from `route a` and other from `route b`

```
(SELECT * -- double set of columns from table [route]
    FROM route a JOIN route b 
    ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
```

You must substitute `*` with field names ommiting duplication of field names

E.g.

```
(SELECT a.*
    FROM route a JOIN route b 
    ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
```

or even better - don't be lazy and write each needed field by name

Comment: Hi, actually 
SELECT *
FROM route a 
JOIN route b ON 
a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
this works without any errors.

Comment: Yes. It works by itself but it can not work in **subselect**